# Eclipse Property view connect wit swt tree widget

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am trying to create eclipse plugin for my application. I am struck and googled a lot to get to the answer. But cant crack the problem. Problem: I am able to create a Swt Tree widget with all the treeItem inside that. Now for each treeitem in tree, I wanted to show different set of properties in eclipse property view. I found examples how to connect Property view with TreeViwer but not for swt Tree widget. Can anyone point me to location where I can find this.
Thanks in advance,
Tor

Answer (score 1):

In your view simply construct a `TreeViewer` rathe than a `Tree` and you're done :-)

You can access the SWT control via `viewer.getTree()`...

Comment: Hi Tonny thanks.. While converting from Tree to TreeVIewer the composite dont display anything. Its full blank. Is the property view not possible by tree what u mean?

Comment: Try to create a new view using the view wizard in Eclipse. The generated code should provide you will all the needed clues :-)

Comment: Hi Tonny, I am pretty new to eclipse. Still learing curve. Can you please let me know how to cretae this new wizard (by steps). Thanks for you quick reply.

Comment: Open your `MANIFEST.MF`. Select `Extensions` page. Click `Add...`. Select `org.eclipse.ui.views` - untick `Show only extension....` if not present. Select `Sample View` at the bottom. Press `Next`. Fill in details.